# Porque o texto pula pra linha de baixo?

Tags: funções, text, quebras-de-linha

Olá! Estou fazendo uma assinatura de e-mail dinâmica e gostaria de colocar alguns "botões" e etc. Fiz um com a função de mostrar o segundo número da empresa, porém ao clicar nele o texto é jogado para a linha de baixo.

Como posso resolver?

**Código HTML**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

 <script>    
    function ocultar(el) {
        var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
        if(display == "none")
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'block';
        else
            document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
    }
   </script>


   <script>    
    function mostrar(id) { Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")).forEach(div => div.style.display = "none"); if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "block"){ document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none"; return; } document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block"; }
   </script>
 
</head>

<body>

<p>Telefone 1: (DDD) XXXX-XXXX&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Telefone 2:

<a id="minhaDiv2" href="#" onclick="ocultar('minhaDiv2'); mostrar('minhaDiv')"> mostrar</a>
<a id="minhaDiv" class="hidden" style="display: none;">(DDD) XXXX-XXXX</a></p>

 <!--&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;--><p><span style="font-weight: lighter;">Celular: (DDD) 9XXXX-XXXX</span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao aplicar `display: block` no elemento, ele vai ocupar toda a largura do contêiner, ficando numa única linha. Elementos de bloco tendem a ocupar a linha inteira.

Aplique `display: inline` em vez disso:

```js
function ocultar(el) {
   var display = document.getElementById(el).style.display;
   if(display == "none")
      document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'inline';
   else
      document.getElementById(el).style.display = 'none';
}

function mostrar(id) {
   Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("hidden")).forEach(div =>
      div.style.display = "none");
      if (document.getElementById(id).style.display == "inline"){
         document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
         return;
      }
      document.getElementById(id).style.display = "inline";
}
```

```html
<p>Telefone 1: (DDD) XXXX-XXXX&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Telefone 2:

<a id="minhaDiv2" href="#" onclick="ocultar('minhaDiv2'); mostrar('minhaDiv')"> mostrar</a>
<a id="minhaDiv" class="hidden" style="display: none;">(DDD) XXXX-XXXX</a></p>

 <!--&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;--><p><span style="font-weight: lighter;">Celular: (DDD) 9XXXX-XXXX</span></p>
```